# WebAssembly without UI Render of Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

I want to migrate one of class project ( C# ) to webassembly but all tutorials include Blazor as input, I don't need a UI part just wasm conversion, any tutorial or help to start with

Comment: Did about you solve it? I have done it recently, curious about your approach